# Connecting to Serial port in QT

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, read-write

I'd like to connect to a microcontroller using `QSerialPort`. I've added the line serial port to my `.pro` file, included `QSerialPort` in my source file and ran `qmake`. My code is below:

```
    serial.setPortName("COM3");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serial.write("ok*");
```

When I run the code I get a message saying the device is not open though I've confirmed it's open with `TeraTerm`. What am I missing? The error message is below:

```
QIODevice::write: device not open
```

Comment: You can't open port with 2 programs in one time, check what open() returns - true or false? If false then call `serial.errorString()` and see error, and don't use one port in 2 or more program. Tell me results.

Comment: The program runs without errors now after I reconnected the microcontroller but I can't see what I've written to it. I should be able to see an OK message in Teraterm but it's blank. Is there another way to confirm my code is writing to the serial? Also, the code is in one of my source files, not the main file, should it be?

Comment: So, am I right, yoo tried open one port in different programms?

Comment: No I only tried to open it in QT, I just need the other program to test I'm writing to the serial port. Initially I had teraterm open before running the code, I think that's similar to what you meant and must have caused the error earlier. Can I check what is being written in any other way?

Comment: You opened it in Qt and teraTerm could not open the port, when you open port with teraTerm, your Qt app can't open it too. You can't open 1 port in 2 apps at the same time

Comment: You're right, so do you have any suggestions on how I can confirm that I'm writing what I type in.

Comment: Do it with your controller, blink the LED light or something else. Only your controller can confirm it, not any other program.

Comment: Alright I could do that, but for reference I've put a link that describes what I mean more accurately if you can spare the time. It's a youtube video where the text is written to a comport and displayed using teraterm. The seconds from 3:10 - 3:20 show what I mean. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UD78xyKbrfk

Comment: Author in this video opened com4 in Qt but com3 in teraterm, it is absolutely different ports, you can do this too(with different ports) But I suppose that this man emulate com port, I use for this purpose com0com. It creates 2 virtual com ports and I can work with this ports as with phisycal ports(but my computer has no any com-port) Is it proper solution for you?

Comment: Do you know how I could it with different ports, I could use com0com if necessary but I'd rather send separate them. Thanks for taking the time to look at the video

Comment: I don't know why do you need this, I used com0com to get a few virtual ports because I have not real ports on my computer. And I don't think that it helps you, suppose you open com1 in Qt, com2 in teraTerm, but where is your contrloller?com3?Write data to com2 and com3 , can teraterm confirm that data was succesfully wrote in controller, I don't think so, controller can confirm this.

Comment: Yh com0com would work for me. com3 is my controller which i open in qt as well. Teraterm can be any other comport, I'll use com0com to link them. Thank you

Comment: So can I add this as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should check is open returns `true`. If no, then tell to user about error and call `errorString()`

```
if(serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    serial.write("ok*");
else
{
    //error
    qDebug() << serial.errorString();
}
```

You try to open one port in different programs. It is forbidden in Windows. So you can't use this. In your [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UD78xyKbrfk) author open `com3` in `Qt` but `com4` in `teraterm`, it is different ports, so you should use same thing, not one port for few programs.

Pay attention on this program: [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)